# Animate view to fullscreen (Card to detail)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to replicate the cards from the Appstore's today tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showDetail = false
    @State var selectedForDetail : Post?

    var posts = [...] // Just sample data: Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor...") etc.


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(self.posts){ current in
                    PostView(post: current, isDetailed: self.$showDetail).onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedForDetail = current
                        withAnimation(.spring()){
                           self.showDetail.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if showDetail {
                PostView(post: selectedForDetail!, isDetailed: self.$showDetail).onTapGesture {
                   withAnimation(.spring()){
                        self.showDetail.toggle()
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PostView : View {

    var post : Post

    @Binding var isDetailed : Bool    

    var body : some View {
       VStack(alignment: .leading){
           HStack(alignment: .top){
               Text(post.subtitle)
               Spacer()
           }.padding([.top, .horizontal])
           Text(post.title).padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
           if isDetailed {
               Text(post.extra).padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
               Spacer()
           }
       }
       .background(isDetailed ? Color.green : Color.white)
       .cornerRadius(isDetailed ? 0 : 16)
       .shadow(radius: isDetailed ? 0 : 12)
       .padding(isDetailed ? [] : [.top, .horizontal])
       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}

struct Post : Identifiable {
   var id = UUID()
   var subtitle : String
   var title : String
   var extra : String
}
```

It works so far that pressing a PostView shows a detailed PostView in fullscreen. But the animation looks way off. I also tried to follow these video tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOQWAzsKi4U

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gDtf22TwW0

But these only worked with static content (and no ScrollView. Using one results in overlapped PostViews) or didn't look right..

So my question is how can i improve my code to get as close as possible to the todays tab in die Appstore? Is my approach even feasible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to show the PostView on top of your views like you are doing. What the app store is doing is only changing the height/width of the actual cell, hence they can animate it the way they did. I will try to fix up your code when I get a chance, hopefully very soon. Additionally, I would prefer using a `List` over using `Foreach` and `ScrollView` especially if you will have images like the App Store. List is basically `UITableView` and it's better optimized to reuse cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below your code modified to fit your needs

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedForDetail : Post?
    @State var showDetails: Bool = false

    // Posts need to be @State so changes can be observed
    @State var posts = [
        Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."),
        Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."),
        Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."),
        Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."),
        Post(subtitle: "test1", title: "title1", extra: "Lorem ipsum dolor...")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(self.posts.indices) { index in
                    GeometryReader { reader in
                        PostView(post: self.$posts[index], isDetailed: self.$showDetails)
                        .offset(y: self.posts[index].showDetails ? -reader.frame(in: .global).minY : 0)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if !self.posts[index].showDetails {
                                self.posts[index].showDetails.toggle()
                                self.showDetails.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        // Change this animation to what you please, or change the numbers around. It's just a preference.
                        .animation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))
                        // If there is one view expanded then hide all other views that are not
                        .opacity(self.showDetails ? (self.posts[index].showDetails ? 1 : 0) : 1)
                    }
                    .frame(height: self.posts[index].showDetails ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : 100, alignment: .center)
                    .simultaneousGesture(
                        // 500 will disable ScrollView effect
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: self.posts[index].showDetails ? 0 : 500)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct PostView : View {
    @Binding var post : Post
    @Binding var isDetailed : Bool
    var body : some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack(alignment: .top){
                Text(post.subtitle)
                Spacer()

                // Only show close button if page is showing in full screen
                if(self.isDetailed) {
                    // Close Button
                    Button(action: {
                        self.post.showDetails.toggle()
                        self.isDetailed.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("X")
                            .frame(width: 48, height: 48, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }.padding([.top, .horizontal])

            Text(post.title).padding([.horizontal, .bottom])

            if isDetailed {
                Text(post.extra).padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(isDetailed ? Color.green : Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(isDetailed ? 0 : 16)
        .shadow(radius: isDetailed ? 0 : 12)
        .padding(isDetailed ? [] : [.top, .horizontal])
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct Post : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var subtitle : String
    var title : String
    var extra : String
    var showDetails: Bool = false // We need this variable to control each cell individually
}
```

If any explanation is needed please let me know.

Note: I added a `showDetails` property to your `Post` model, this is needed to control individual cells. Keep in mind best practice is to separate that into a different array to take care of whats visible and what not but this will do for now.

Also note we are looping through indices of our array and not the objects, this way we have flexibility of choosing what to show.

Comment: To answer your concerns: 1. I prefer you don't have dynamic height, even the Apple store doesn't, they have only couple different cells types which are fixed to height. As far as the image, well you can make the card to be a ratio of your typical images, say 1:2 (height always double your width) this way you can fix width to 100 and height to 200 and all of your images to be resizable to fit their parent (in this case its our PostView) thats what Apple is doing as well, if you need further clarity let me know.

Comment: For 2) you are seeing the animation of them taking their position, is it possible to remove that? yes it definitely is, but I will let you play around and try to figure it out. I am currently at work and time is a little bit limited ^^ if you struggle, create a new question and hopefully I or someone will be able to help you. re-bug: can you explain what do you mean by off? for me I see it normal whether first or 2nd time.

Comment: Got it. There are many ways but unfortunately none is as straight forward. Checkout this link, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060530/swiftui-resizable-list-height-that-dependent-on-an-element-count