# Swiftui List Row Dynamic Height

Tags: list, dynamic, swiftui, editmode

I have a question about List Row Dynamic in SwiftUI;
how reset height of row when EditMode of List changed, For now, ui element of Row has changed, but height of row in the list not update to fit.

[inactive editmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzFhD.png)

[active editmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGKol.png)

anyone know how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: Would you provide related code?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.fixedSize`.
Example

```
List {
    ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
        //Your list row view
          .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // <-- Here
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
```