# How to display a List or Table without empty rows at bottom?

Tags: swiftui, row, swiftui-list, swiftui-table

I'm looking for a way to display a SwiftUI `Table` or `List` at its "intrinsic size" without including empty rows or empty space below the rows, as it does in the following example, in which the table is given a blue border for clarity:

[image: Example]

It is generated by the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Achmed", "Balthus", "Chaim"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("List of Names")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            List(names, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
                .border(.blue)
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the `Spacer()` to reduce the height of the `List`, removing the extra space inside the `List` View below its last row - but it does not.

Nor does adding `.fixedSize()` modifier. (I wonder why the list doesn't have an `idealHeight` that does not include empty rows, such that adding `.fixedSize()` would cause it to be displayed that way.)

Comment: Try adding `.listStyle(.grouped)`

Comment: @koen Thanks. That does eliminate blank rows, but it doesn't eliminate the space they occupy; the table still takes up the excess space I'm trying to eliminate. (Also, it's iOS-specific and I'm looking for a solution that works for macOS as well.)

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060530/swiftui-resizable-list-height-that-dependent-on-an-element-count

Comment: Thanks again, @koen! What that posts seeks for is a way to resize the rows to take up more/less space. In contrast, I want each row to take up its preferred amount; I don't seek to change that. Rather, I just want to eliminate any extra padding that's included at the bottom of the List. So unfortunately I don't see how it applies.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a picture of what the final result should look like and other requirements that you mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @koen I changed the example a bit for clarity (and made it iOS instead of macOS).

Answer (score 0):

This works for iOS, I changed the listStyle to `insetGrouped` and commented out `padding()`. Also, `alternatingRowBackgrounds` gave a compiler error, so I commented that one out as well.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Achmed", "Balthus", "Chaim"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("List of Names")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            List(names, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
                .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
//                .alternatingRowBackgrounds()
//                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

For macOS, you could try `.listStyle(.automatic)`.

EDIT: try using a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Achmed", "Balthus", "Chaim"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("List of Names")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            GeometryReader { g in
                List(names, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
                    .frame(height: g.size.height / 3)
                    .border(.blue)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

You will have to tweak the `.frame(height: g.size.height / 3)` part for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the List in your example is still occupying the excess space I'm trying to eliminate, rather than appearing at its intrinsic size. You can see that if you insert the line `Text("BOTTOM")` after `Spacer()` in your code.

Comment: Not at my Mac to test, but my guess is `Spacer()` is using all that space. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the spacer. You can tell because the List is gray, whereas the `Spacer()` is white, just as in your screenshot (you can see it as a white sliver at the bottom of your screen). Adding the `Text("BOTTOM")` the gray List comes down nearly to the word BOTTOM, which is pressed against the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thank you @koen. I appreciate your continued efforts! But your revised approach, using `GeometryReader`, is specific to one particular screen geometry, one dynamic font size, one screen orientation, exactly 3 elements in the list, etc. I need a general purpose solution that will work without knowledge of all those things.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't think you can do it with a List. You might try something like this:

struct ContentView: View {
let names = ["Achmed", "Balthus", "Chaim"]

@State var textSize:CGSize = .zero
@State var listSize:CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Text("List of Names")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .readSize { size in
                    textSize = size
                }
                .border(.green)
            VStack{
                VStack {
                    ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0).padding(2)
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
                .readSize { size in
                    listSize = size
                }
                .frame(width: textSize.width, height: listSize.height)
                .background(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .padding()
            }
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
           .border(.blue)
             Text("Bottom of list")
            Spacer()
            Text("Bottom of page")
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
extension View {
func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
        }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
}
```

}

You'll also have to define the following Struct.

```
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Result:

[image]